# SmartForm content is not displayed in code-behind

Tags: xsd, ektron

I added smartForm group content in Ektron. Then, added corresponding elements in .xsd file, something like the following in EmployeeForm.xsd file.

```
<xs:element name="Employee">
         <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" />           
             </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Further, I mannually added the above complex type as EmployeeForm.cs in auto-generated class called EktForm.cs, something like below:

```
public partial class EmployeeForm
{

   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public string ID{ get; set; }
}
```

Yet, I am still unable to get EmployeeForm.Name and EmployeeForm.ID in the code-behind by doing following:

```
var ektContent= SmartFormFactory.GetSmartForm<EktForm>();
empName.Text = ektContent.EmployeeForm.Name;
empID.Text = ektContent.EmployeeForm.ID;
```

What I am missing ? Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Can I ask why you had to manually edit the xsd?  Ektron is pretty good at hiding all that stuff and translating the fields into the necessary xsd mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: I was referring to the .xsd file in web application, not in the Ektron content manager's smartForm configuration. Contents added in Ektron is all good. The issue is in the web application that is trying to access the contents that newly added.

Comment: There isn't enough information to help you. What is SmartFormFactory? Why are you manually creating XSDs? Your code does not seem to include any references to content items - usually you would GetItem() by passing in an ID.

Comment: Thx for your input. It is resolved.